# migration in .NET Core of Request["companyId"]

Tags: asp.net-core

I am working to migrate a .NET Framework MVC project in .NET Core 5.0. Many controllers contains instructions like:

```
    public ActionResult Details(int empId, int partnerId)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnURL = Request["companyId"];
        ....
```

How can I migrate this piece of code in .NET core ?
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Httpcontext.request.xxx` to get the data in request in `Asp.Net Core`,

First, You need to add `HttpContextAccessor` interface in your DI container:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Then inject it in your controller.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    
    public HomeController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    public ActionResult Details(int empId, int partnerId)
    {
        //use this code to get the data you want

        _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.xxxxx
    }
}
```

More details please refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-context?view=aspnetcore-6.0)